# Is this an ambiguity in antlr4 grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am trying to parse input like this:

```
(0002,0980);
(000a,f987);
(0001,[foo]00);
```

The pattern is ( g, e);
where g is a four-digit hex number. If g is even, e is a four-digit hex number either even or odd. If g is odd, e has the pattern '[IDENT] hex-digit hex-digit'.

I have tried many variations but this summarizes my thinking...

```
grammar Post;


script : statement (statement)* EOF ;

statement : tag ';' ;

tag : even_tag | odd_tag ;

even_tag : '(' g_even ',' e_even ')' ;
odd_tag  : '(' g_odd ',' e_odd ')' ;

g_even : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;
g_odd  : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ODD_HEXDIGIT ;
e_even : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;
e_odd  : '[' IDENT ']' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;

HEXDIGIT : ODD_HEXDIGIT | EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;

ODD_HEXDIGIT    :   ['1','3','5','7','9', 'b', 'B', 'd', 'D', 'f', 'F'];

EVEN_HEXDIGIT   :   ['0','2','4','6','8', 'a', 'A', 'c', 'C', 'e', 'E'];

IDENT  : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | ' ')*;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment DIGIT  : ('0'..'9');
```

It fails with the un-inspiring error
line 2:12 token recognition error at: '\n'
line 3:4 no viable alternative at input '(0001'

Modifying this to

```
grammar P2;

script : statement (statement)* EOF ;

statement : tag ';' ;

tag : even_tag | odd_tag ;

even_tag : '(' g_even ',' e_even ')' ;
odd_tag  : '(' g_odd ',' e_odd ')' ;

g_even : G_EVEN ;
g_odd  : G_ODD ;
e_even : E_EVEN ;
e_odd  : E_ODD ;

G_EVEN : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;
G_ODD  : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ODD_HEXDIGIT ;
E_EVEN : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;
E_ODD  : '[' IDENT ']' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;

ODD_HEXDIGIT    :   ['1','3','5','7','9', 'b', 'B', 'd', 'D', 'f', 'F'];

EVEN_HEXDIGIT   :   ['0','2','4','6','8', 'a', 'A', 'c', 'C', 'e', 'E'];

HEXDIGIT : ODD_HEXDIGIT | EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;

IDENT  : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | ' ')*;

fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment DIGIT  : ('0'..'9');
```

helps alot but the problem looks more clearly like an ambiguity in e.

```
line 2:5 mismatched input ',098' expecting ','
line 2:12 token recognition error at: '\n'
```

I suspect the problem results from the fact that g_even and e_even are ambiguous and g_odd and e_even are ambiguous.  However, the pattern is such that this ambiguity can be avoided because g is always parsed first and g_even and g_odd are not ambiguous.  Once g is known, there is no ambiguity left. There is only ambiguity if the parser doesn't know it is always looking for g first.  There is only ambiguity if parsing might begin with e and that is never the case.

Perhaps the problem isn't ambiguity at all.  I'm new to this game.
How can I parse this so that the parse tree labels g_even, g_odd, e_even, e_odd?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with the following:

```
grammar P2;

script : statement (statement)* EOF ;

statement : tag ';' ;

tag : even_tag | odd_tag ;

even_tag : '(' g_even ',' e_even ')' ;
odd_tag  : '(' g_odd ',' e_odd ')' ;

g_even : G_EVEN ;
g_odd  : G_ODD ;
e_even : G_EVEN | G_ODD;
e_odd  : E_ODD ;

G_EVEN : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;
G_ODD  : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ODD_HEXDIGIT ;
//E_EVEN : HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;
E_ODD  : '[' IDENT ']' HEXDIGIT HEXDIGIT ;

ODD_HEXDIGIT    :   [13579bBdDfF];

EVEN_HEXDIGIT   :   [02468aAcCeE];

HEXDIGIT : ODD_HEXDIGIT | EVEN_HEXDIGIT ;

IDENT  : LETTER (LETTER | DIGIT | ' ')*;


fragment LETTER : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ;

fragment DIGIT  : ('0'..'9');
```

There was no need to define the overlapping E_EVEN. Plus, the list-of-charcters-to-match syntax was wrong and caused unintended matching on commas. Doh.

Comment: It could've been simpler if you allowed ANTLR to parse all cases regardless of parity, and then did a validating pass in code over the CST.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the art to this.  We have options: lexer? parser? tree-walker?  I thought this was cool because one only needs to read the grammar to see what is happening and the parser does all the lifting. But this is only a small part of a bigger problem.  I may change my tune if I run into conflicts as I expand this.